# SSL certificat error on stripe payment module

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I made a personnal plugin for use Stripe on my website. I have 2 questions.
First, i have this error when verifCertSsl is to true :
 **"error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: CApath: /etc/ssl/certs". My website is using OVH eand HTTPS connection.**
 I don't know why i have this error. When the method verifCertSsl is to false everything works, but there is no data security.

And the second question, how can i pass client datas to stripe like first name, last name, email, adress. I have this :

```
 var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
//add owne info
var ownerInfo = {
amount: document.querySelector('#amount'),
currency: 'eur',
owner: {
  nom: document.querySelector('#name'),
  prenom: document.querySelector('#prenom'),
  adresse: document.querySelector('#adresse'),
  zip: document.querySelector('#zip'),
  ville: document.querySelector('#ville'),
  email: document.querySelector('#email')
},
};
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

stripe.createToken(card, ownerInfo).then(function(result) {
  if (result.error) {
    // Inform the user if there was an error
    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
  } else {
    // Send the source to your server
    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
  }
});
```

});

but i retrieve nothing. 
After a successful payment i don't receive email, while i use "receipt_email" :

```
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key);

        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                'amount' => $amount, // $10
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'card' => $token,
                //"customer" => "cus_AFGbOSiITuJVDs",
                //"source" => "src_18eYalAHEMiOZZp1l9ZTjSU0",
                'receipt_email' => $email,
            )
        );
```

for information i use wordpress
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

> First, i have this error when verifCertSsl is to true : "error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: CApath: /etc/ssl/certs". My website is using OVH eand HTTPS connection. I don't know why i have this error. When the method verifCertSsl is to false everything works, but there is no data security.

A common cause for this error is that the `data/ca-certificates.crt` file is not included in your [PHP installation](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/data/ca-certificates.crt), or it has file permissions that is preventing your code from accessing it. Once you have done this, you should be fine (and the SSL handshake between your server and our API should work fine).

> And the second question, how can i pass client datas to stripe like
>   first name, last name, email, adress.

The issue here is that you are not passing the address information properly to the API. Stripe's API has specific names for each property or parameter and those are also in English. To pass the address information on tokenization your code would look like this:

```
var options = {
  name: document.getElementById('name').value,
  address_line1: document.getElementById('address-line1').value,
  address_line2: document.getElementById('address-line2').value,
  address_city: document.getElementById('address-city').value,
  address_state: document.getElementById('address-state').value,
  address_zip: document.getElementById('address-zip').value,
  address_country: document.getElementById('address-country').value,
};
stripe.createToken(card, options).then(setOutcome);
```

You can see a basic example here: https://jsfiddle.net/4o5msan0/

> After a successful payment i don't receive email, while i use "receipt_email" :

I think the issue here is that you are not passing `receipt_email` properly and the `$email` variable might be empty. You need to make sure that you have retrieved this value from the browser which means your form needs to post it explicitly. It won't be retrieve from the token. If you do, then remember that Stripe does not send email receipts in Test mode, only in Live mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help ;)